# How to change tr color on mouse over when there is already implemented?

Tags: html, css, background, html-table

I am working on existing project. I created a simple table.

```
<table border='0' width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I did not apply any CSS class on table but still it is showing blue background color when I mouse over on `tr`. So there is already some CSS implemented on `table` somewhere. I want to disable this effect but I can't change existing CSS.

How can I stop this mouse over effect on this specific table. I tried some inline CSS but it did not work yet.

Comment: Can we see your css files? Since we cannot be able to replicate your issue. or any working example will also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `!important` on your css which should override existing css

```
tr:hover {
  background:red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey writing this css will disable his functionality throughout the website. wrong idea.

Comment: he just want to override to existing css so this should work fine

Comment: @Murtaza: I know but I tried it with css class. For example: `.someclass tr:hover {
  background:red !important;
}`. So nice idea.

Comment: if there a single table then it's a good idea otherwise is not an good idea.

Comment: well, he hasn't asked for any specific, and this is just an example how he can override existing, if he is cleaver he can use this any specific `tr`

Comment: @user1193749 - we are not here to judge who is clever and who is not. This is a question answer website. and you are just helping to all those people visiting this question in future. so please be specific to your anwser. explain your answer. and provide details, so that it is useful to all.

Comment: if you have best answer just post it otherwise there is not point to argue as long as the op is happy with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reassign css property using "!important;" keyword. Simply create the new css property with this keyword and bind it to necessary tag. I think this is a hack, but in any cases it very helps me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the hover changes only to this table tr , then its better to assign an ID or class to the table and then write the CSS.

```
.tableclass tr:hover{
            background:none !important;
 }
```